# Not allowed to call Show() multiple times before a Chooser returns

Tags: windows-phone-7

i need to use two choosers in wp7, one is PhotoChooserTask , another one is CameraCaptureTask,i only need to user one of them  each time, how can i stop one before start another ,it will throw an exception if i start another before the first one returns.thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate

```
somechooser.Show();
```

inside a try-catch block.

It will catch the exception if the user tries to open another chooser before the last one was either opened or properly closed.

Comment: hi,it did not throw an exception, but i wanna open the second one, how can i stop the first ?

Comment: If it didn't throw an exception, does it mean that it worked? You can't close a chooser from your app while it's running. User needs to go back to your app using the back button to close the chooser.